# Create ts variables from matrix, given list of variable names

Tags: r, variables, matrix, time-series

I have a 265x7 matrix from FRED data, called `data` and created a list of variable names from the headers, using `varlist = names(data)[2:7]`

What I would like to do is to extract columns `2:7` from `data` and place them into a `ts` object, each named by the corresponding name stored in `varlist`. I'm relatively new to R. What I managed so far is to create numeric variables, using

```
lapply(varlist,function(x){assign(x,data[,x],envir = .GlobalEnv)})
```

What I would like to achieve, though, is to create `ts` objects with attributes `start = c(1947,1), frequency = 4`

How, if possible, would I implement this into the above function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `lapply` here. The `ts` constructor accepts `matrix` and `data.frame` (`mts`)

```
set.seed(42)
fred_mat <- matrix(rnorm(265 * 7), ncol = 7,
                   dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:7]))

varlist <- colnames(fred_dat)[2:7]

fred_ts <- ts(fred_mat[, varlist], frequency = 4, start = c(1947, 1))

str(fred_ts)
 ## mts [1:265, 1:6] 1.065 0.813 -0.191 -2.7 0.061 ...
 ## - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ##  ..$ : NULL
 ##  ..$ : chr [1:6] "B" "C" "D" "E" ...
 ## - attr(*, "tsp")= num [1:3] 1947 2013 4
 ## - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "mts" "ts" "matrix"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `ts` giving a matrix. And no need to set names manually , it will pick matrix names and use them as time series names.

```
     ts(data[2:7], start = c(1947, 1), frequency = 4)
```

here an example, I give ts a named matrix:

```
   ts(matrix(rnorm(3*5), nrow=3, ncol=5,
           dimnames=list(NULL,paste0('var',1:5))), 
           start = c(1947, 1), frequency = 4)
             var1        var2       var3       var4       var5
1947 Q1 1.3972600 -1.29789587 -0.4044754  1.8445556 -0.6240791
1947 Q2 0.8193313 -0.45867923 -0.3486047 -0.4864113  1.2318401
1947 Q3 0.5614728 -0.07158473 -1.0102497  1.5096153  0.4490764
```

Comment: It's funny that we answered exactly at the same time :)

Comment: This is great! My `lapply` command actually works on the `mts` you create, so I could split it as well if needed. Thanks!